# TypeError: props.items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting the same error no matter what I do. Please give me the easiest solution possible.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import React from "react";

const NewsItem = (props) => {
  //   console.log(props.item);
    const item = props.items.map((e) => {
      return e.id;
    });
  console.log(props.items);
  // console.log(props.items.title)
  return <div>{item}</div>;
};
```

Comment: what does `props.items` shows on consoling

Comment: The provided component definition is fine. Search for errors in usages of this component (in other files)

Comment: what is the value of props.items?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use React [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). Use your required schema definition for the prop `item` inside this. This will help the compiler to identify the type of the prop.

```
ComponentName.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(arrayOf)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const NewsItem = ({ items = [] }) => {
    const itemsList = items.map((item) => item.id);
    return <div> { itemsList.join(', ') } </div>;
};
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this errors because when you render the `NewsItem` the props `items` is not provide or it's provide with it value not an array. To avoid that you take advantage of [propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) and specify the default value of the props `items` when the `NewsItem` component is render without passing the props items.

```
const NewsItem = (props) => {
    // other code goes here
    return <div></div>
}

NewsItem.defaultProps = {
    items: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from "react";
import React from "react";

const NewsItem = ({ items = [], ...props }) => {
  //   console.log(props.item);
    const item = items.map((e) => {
      return e.id;
    });
  console.log(items);
  // console.log(props.items.title)
  return <div>{item}</div>;
};
```

Obviously your error is in the caller of this component, the snippet above will replace ay undefined value in your props with the empty array.
To fix the error you will need to either fix the caller or handle the fact that items is not an array, maybe such as:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import React from "react";

const NewsItem = ({ items = [], ...props }) => {
 
    if (!Array.isArray(items)) return <span>No items found</span>;
    const item = items.map((e) => {
      return e.id;
    });
  console.log(items);
  // console.log(props.items.title)
  return <div>{item}</div>;
};
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. You are just getting rid of the error but not the underlying problem, which is that items is obviously not an array.